# Integrating $\int \frac{x \cos x+1}{\sqrt{2x^3e^{\sin x}+x^2}}dx$

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

I came across a question today..

> Integrate $\int \dfrac{x \cos x+1}{\sqrt{2x^3e^{\sin x}+x^2}}dx$

**How to do it?** I tried to take $x^2 e^{\sin x}$ out of the roots. But it didn't work out. I also tried to used substitution method by with the whole denominator but no result.

Comment: I'd love to see how to solve such an antiderivative. WA has no idea, and neither do I, what to do. It looks evil.

Comment: Is it a problem for students? What course?

Comment: @YuriyS It's like high level high school problem.. :p

Comment: Depends on the country, I guess. We had nothing like this in high-school

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Take $x e^{\sin x}$ =t/2 and you will get the answer.
Multiply the numerator and the denominator by ${e^{\sin x}}$ and pull $x^2$ out of the root.
$\int{dt\over t\sqrt{t+1}}$.Now substitute $t+1=y^{2}$.

Comment: Excellent! It really works. +1

Comment: Yes, I had my doubt's when reading this but now I've tried it, I'd say this was amazing. (+1)